# dispatchKeyEvent calling method twice

Tags: java, android

I've implemented dispatchKeyEvent in my activity to listen to the Enter key being pressed.
The problem is that when i click enter,it calls my method twice ? How can i fix this ?
Thanks,have a nice day !

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

              enter();
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
};
```

Comment: try KeyEvent.getAction()

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Fixed it,done this :
At first i was doing `ACTION_DOWN` but that was triggering an older problem of mine.

```
 @Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){

         enter();

            return true;
    }}
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
};
```